# log4j and websphere 6.1 configuration

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, log4j, websphere

How to configure log4j for websphere 6.1 as my jsp code contains display tag, even though i have added the log4j jars in the WEB-INF/lib folder it shows the below error on the console whenever trying to view the page through the WAS server.

```
 SystemErr     R log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.displaytag.properties.TableProperties).
 SystemErr     R log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the message is just a notification that log4j hasn't been configured to log messages from org.displaytag.properties.TableProperties class (if any)..

this is not an issue as such.. usually this can be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

seems like you're missing the log4j.properties. Put that file in your classpath

Answer (score 0):

@ananth No it cant be ignored what if the display tag doesnt have any effect while viewing the page i suggest the log4j properties file should be added